# Mandar erro para login duplicado C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou implementando um sistema de login, mas não consigo mandar uma error message para quando tento criar um login duplicado.
Declarei o login da seguinte forma:

```
[Index("User_UserName_Index", IsUnique = true)]
public string Login { get; set; }
```

Mas não consigo retornar um erro falando que *o login ja existe*

Pensei em usar um `try`, mas não sei como eu poderia fazer isso.

Para a verificação do login eu fiz da seguinte forma

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{

    Contexto db = new Contexto();
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (TempData["ViewData"] != null) 
        {
            ViewData = (ViewDataDictionary)TempData["ViewData"];
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Autenticar(string login, string senha)
    {

        try
        {
            var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Login == login && p.Senha == senha);

            if (usuario.Admim == true)
            {
                Session["admLogado"] = usuario;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuarios");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["usuarioLogado"] = usuario;
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Usuario ou senha invalidos");
            TempData["ViewData"] = ViewData;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Por que o Login estaria duplicado? Não valida se já existe um usuário com os mesmos dados no momento do cadastro?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo com o try-catch você não vai conseguir validar que o login já existe.
Veja:

> **FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable)**
>
> Retorna o primeiro elemento de uma sequência ou um valor padrão se a
>   sequência não contém elementos

Ou seja, ele não lança uma exeception caso o valor não esteja na coleção, sendo assim não irá cair no seu catch.
Para isso você pode utilizar a função `First()` no lugar de `FirstOrDefault()`, esta sim lança o exeception.
Veja esses links para saber mais sobre as funções [FirstOrDefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) e [First](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que buscar alguma informação de usuário e não encontrar, iria cair no `catch` ao tentar acessar a informação de "*Admin*", retornando um `NullPointer`.

Tente assim:

```js
public ActionResult Autenticar(string login, string senha)
{
 var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Login == login && p.Senha == senha);

 if (usuario != null)
 {
  if (usuario.Admim)
  {
   Session["admLogado"] = usuario;
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuarios");
  }
  else
  {
   Session["usuarioLogado"] = usuario;
   return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
  }
 }
 else
 {
  ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Usuario ou senha invalidos");
  TempData["ViewData"] = ViewData;
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Autenticar(string login, string senha)
{

    try
    {
        var usuarios = db.Usuarios.Where(p => p.Login == login && p.Senha == senha);

      if(usuarios.Count==0)
      {
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Usuario ou senha invalidos");
         TempData["ViewData"] = ViewData;
         return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
      }
     else if(usuarios.Count==1)
     {
        var usuario=usuarios.First(); 
        if (usuario.Admim == true)
        {
            Session["admLogado"] = usuario;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuarios");
        }
        else
        {
            Session["usuarioLogado"] = usuario;
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
      }
    else
    {
      //Login Duplicado
    }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Erro inesperado
    }

}
```

Acredito que desse jeito funcione, porém eu acho que deverias verificar o login duplicado ao fazer o cadastro.

A Exception não serve para esses tipos de tratamento como mensagem de: *usuario ou senha invalidos*, se por ventura ocorrer uma Exception qualquer a mensagem será sempre a mesma.